# Use Puppet user resource in custom type

Tags: puppet

I am writing a Puppet custom type. One of the things this type does is to create and delete users. One way I could do this is to use the `useradd` and `userdel` commands. But is there a way to do this using the already-existing user resource types in Puppet? This would seem a more portable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
#Defined inside a module name 'testmodule'
#/etc/puppet/modules/testmodule/manifests/userdefine.pp

class testmodule::userdefine ($ensure, $group, $home, $shell) {
  user { $name :
    ensure => $ensure,
    group => $group,
    home => $home,
    shell => $shell,
  }
}

testmodule::userdefine { 'puppet' :
  ensure => present,
  group => "puppet",
  home => "/var/lib/puppet",
  shell => "/sbin/nologin",
}
```

Comment: I am writing a custom type in Ruby, so I need something that works in that context.